# setting DPI of png image in java

Tags: java

I am uing the following code to set dpi of the [ng file. This code is shown in one of the thread of this site only..But I am unable to understand the first line of this code which creates exception :

```
static BufferedImage gridImage;
....

private static void saveGridImage(File output) throws IOException {
output.delete();

final String formatName = "png";

for (Iterator<ImageWriter> iw = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(formatName); iw.hasNext();) {
   ImageWriter writer = iw.next();
   ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
   ImageTypeSpecifier typeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(typeSpecifier, writeParam);
   if (metadata.isReadOnly() || !metadata.isStandardMetadataFormatSupported()) {
      continue;
   }

   setDPI(metadata);

   final ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(output);
   try {
      writer.setOutput(stream);
      writer.write(metadata, new IIOImage(gridImage, null, metadata), writeParam);
   } finally {
      stream.close();
   }
   break;
}
 }

 private static void setDPI(IIOMetadata metadata) throws IIOInvalidTreeException {

// for PMG, it's dots per millimeter
double dotsPerMilli = 1.0 * 300 / 10 / 2.54;

IIOMetadataNode horiz = new IIOMetadataNode("HorizontalPixelSize");
horiz.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(dotsPerMilli));

IIOMetadataNode vert = new IIOMetadataNode("VerticalPixelSize");
vert.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(dotsPerMilli));

IIOMetadataNode dim = new IIOMetadataNode("Dimension");
dim.appendChild(horiz);
dim.appendChild(vert);

IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode("javax_imageio_1.0");
root.appendChild(dim);

metadata.mergeTree("javax_imageio_1.0", root);
 }
```

Exception is :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
```

Please help me to figure out because I am new to java..

Comment: You need to check where (method, line) the exception is thrown.

Comment: on this line
writer.write(metadata, new IIOImage(gridImage, null, metadata), writeParam);

Comment: `1.0 * 300 / 10 / 2.54 == 300 / 25.4`

Answer (score 0):

`gridImage` field is apparently never assigned, when `new IIOImage(gridImage, null, metadata)` is called it's null.

Comment: will you help me how to assign to bufferedimage object?I know this may be silly question for you but I am new...Thank you in advance..

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know where you are supposed to get the image from. What about the `static BufferedImage gridImage;` ? What is that "gridImage"? If you are a beginner, you should try with something simple (just write the PNG, forget about DPI). Also, you should learn how to debug (using an IDE, like Eclipse), stepping so that you can understand what is going on.